# Writing a SQL query in a different way

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have written a query to check the completeness of my table with a universal table. The query is a s follows

```
SELECT * FROM Universal
WHERE UNIVERSAL.TYPE=MYTYPE
  AND Universal.CLASS=MYCLASS
  AND Universal.ID NOT IN (SELECT Mytable.ID FROM Mytable)
```

As you see I filter the universal table before looking for completeness, both in the same query. I Now found that when I remove the NOT IN part, the query runs fine ,but when I include it  I get no result. Whats wrong in this query? How can I write in some other form like using joins or something?

Comment: Are you using MySQL and/or Oracle.

Comment: @jarlh I am writing an query in SQL in excel.

Comment: Why do you expect it to return results? Surely that should only be the case if your data wasn't 'complete' ? This query will only return a result when there is a record in `Universal` with `type=mytype` and `class=myclass` that is not also in 'myTable'. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @StevieG It's like universal table has 1000 rows and mytable has 100. First I filter it using all the properties , which will bring the universal table to arounf 105-110 rows and then I check for ID to find which rows are missing

Comment: In that case it'll be as @jarlh suggests - you have null values in your ID column (which is a very bad design!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Universal
WHERE UNIVERSAL.TYPE=MYTYPE
  AND Universal.CLASS=MYCLASS
  AND Universal.ID NOT IN (SELECT Mytable.ID FROM Mytable
                           WHERE Mytable.ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Nulls and not in...!

The `SELECT` returns rows where the `WHERE` clause is `TRUE`, and doesn't return `FALSE` rows.

Also `UNKNOWN` rows aren't returned (i.e. `NULL` rows.) That's usually not a problem, but when it comes to `NOT IN` many programmers get surprised.

Say you have a cars table, and you want to return cars with colors that are not found in a list (or sub-query):

```
select * from cars where color not in ('red', 'blue')
```

is easy to understand, all cars but red and blue are returned.

But if the list of colors are extended with an unknown color (`NULL`), it will be:

```
select * from cars where color not in ('red', 'blue', NULL)
```

Now the `WHERE` clause doesn't know if e.g. a yellow car is in the list or not, it's not red or blue for sure, but we can't tell if it's not that unknown `NULL` color... I.e. the `WHERE` clause becomes unknown, and no row is returned!

Here the programmer can aviod unknown colors by specifying `IS NOT NULL` in the sub-query. (Or transform to a `NOT EXISTS`, which is "null safe".)

Comment: I would estimate about a 99.9% chance that this is the problem.

Comment: @jarlh I am getting results now. Can you please comment on why that was required. Thanks.

Comment: @user3504466, explanation added.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to SELECT everything from Universal that is not in Mytable?
Using a LEFT JOIN will select everything from and Univeral and only rows from Mytable that match up to something in Universal. So if Mytable.ID is null then that row of Universal does not have a matching row in Mytable:

```
SELECT * FROM Universal
LEFT JOIN Universal.ID = Mytable.ID
WHERE UNIVERSAL.TYPE=MYTYPE
  AND Universal.CLASS=MYCLASS
  AND Mytable.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: did you mean `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: six of one, half dozen of the other.

Comment: The `OUTER` is optional here. The construct itself is called ANTI JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Universal U
WHERE U.TYPE=MYTYPE
AND U.CLASS=MYCLASS
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Mytable WHERE ID = U.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try and have a look at it.

Comment: You don't need IS NOT NULL when it's a NOT EXISTS.